# Nestled List Comprehension using Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
mydict = {
              'Alpha' : {'l':'a','n':1,'q':3,'z':4},
              'Beta'  : {'l':'b','n':2,'q':2,'z':5},
              'Gamma' : {'l':'c','n':3,'q':1,'z':6}
         }
# Or
mydict = {'Alpha': {'l': 'a', 'n': 1, 'q':3, 'z':4}, 'Beta': {'l': 'b', 'n': 2, 'q':2, 'z':5}, 'Gamma': {'l': 'c', 'n': 3, 'q':1, 'z':6}}
```

My output need to be:

```
[['Alpha:','a',1,3,4],['Beta:','b',2,2,5],['Gamma:',c,3,1,6]]
# Or
[
    ['Alpha:' ,'a'  ,1  ,3  ,4],
    ['Beta:'  ,'b'  ,2  ,2  ,5],
    ['Gamma:' ,'c'  ,3  ,1  ,6]
]
```

I goal this making:

```
[[x,y['l'],y['n'],y['q'],y['z']] for x,y in mydict.items()]
```

But I don't want to use `y['l'],y['n']`, I want to use another dictionary comprehension. Is this possible?, For example, if I modify my key `'l'` to `'a'` the code won't work and if I add a new key `'x'`, it won't be displayed.

**PD:** It doesn't matter if numbers are integers or strings (prefer string).

Comment: Are the colons in the output strings intentional?

Comment: @chepner, Do you mean about [] of the result? Yes, I need them. I'll put the result in [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module

Comment: it's definitely possible, but note that dictionaries are unordered, so the order of the entries will be arbitrarily ordered. Something like `[[x] + y.values() for x, y in mydict.items()]`, for example

Comment: @Hamms, if I put `[[x] + y.values() for x, y in mydict.items()]`, give me error. `"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict_values") to list."`

Comment: @Hamms, I found a upgrade of your code: this `[[x, *y.values()] for x, y in mydict.items()]` work perfectly.

Comment: Just pointing out you are using list comprehensions.

Comment: @Asignor, omg, you are right!

Comment: Ah, my apologies; my code was python-2.x, even though you clearly wanted python-3.x

Comment: @Hamms, don't worry, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the idea of Hamms in comments I found a solution:

```
[[x+':', *y.values()] for x, y in mydict.items()]
```

This give the right output.

Comment: Your code suffers from the assumption that the dict keys will be sorted the same way. While that is true today, you should sort by the keys to prevent future dict implementations where the order changes.

Comment: @mattmc3, This dictionary will not get new values, so I like his sort, Is there something wrong? I couldn't understand your comment very well... sorry.

Comment: It's coincidental that 'l', 'n', 'q', and 'z' keys appear in order in all 3 nested dicts. Piggy-backing on your answer, the future-proof solution is something more like `[[x, [z[1] for z in sorted(y.items())]] for x, y in mydict.items()]`

Comment: @mattmc3, sorry, What is the difference between **my code** and **your code**. My doesn't accept new keys and your does? Your corde sort my keys alphabeticaly?

Comment: `*y.values()` makes an assumption that all 3 dicts will return their values in the same order (by key). My implementation removes that assumption and guarantees it.

Comment: @mattmc3, great, interesting code, I my case I don't need it because this won't never happend, but perfect.

Comment: Yours is still the best answer, which is why I upvoted and only commented, rather than add another answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Mattmc3, If you put your suggestion like an aswer I'll accept and vote up, I have no problem, your code is better than the mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
mydict = {'Alpha': {'l': 'a', 'n': 1, 'q':3, 'z':4}, 'Beta': {'l': 'b', 'n': 2, 'q':2, 'z':5}, 'Gamma': {'l': 'c', 'n': 3, 'q':1, 'z':6}}

new_list = [[i]+b.values() for i, b in mydict.items()]
```

Comment: This give me error, but using a similar code `[[x, *y.values()] for x, y in mydict.items()]` I get the output.

Comment: This solution is for Python 2 only. A script that will work for Python 3 would be @Ender Look's.

Comment: Ahh, py2... In tag I put py3.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each level of the dictionary and append the values as strings to a nested list.

```
outLst = []

for oKey in mydict.keys():
    outLst.append([oKey+':'])
    for iKey in mydict[oKey]:
        outLst[-1].append(str(mydict[oKey][iKey]))
print outLst
```

where the output is:

`[['Alpha:', '3', '4', 'a', '1'], ['Beta:', '2', '5', 'b', '2'], ['Gamma:', '1', '6', 'c', '3']]`

If you want the output list to be sorted, I can modify the code to do that.

Comment: Is there a way to make this in one line?

Answer (score 1):

```
[ [ key+':', *value.values()] for key,value in mydict.items()]

[['Alpha:', 'a', 1, 3, 4], ['Beta:', 'b', 2, 2, 5], ['Gamma:', 'c', 3, 1, 6]]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Your code works fine, but I found the answer 10 hours ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44211438/7655838).So I'll only up vote you. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[x] + y.values() for x, y in mydict.items()]
```

Comment: `[[x] + y.values() for x, y in mydict.items()]` give error. I found the solution using `[[x, *y.values()] for x, y in mydict.items()]`.

Comment: What error? My code works for me on your data. Output is `[['Alpha', 3, 4, 'a', 1], ['Beta', 2, 5, 'b', 2], ['Gamma', 1, 6, 'c', 3]]`

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict_values") to list`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @EnderLook My code works for me with python 3.4 and your code raises `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`. Seems you you're using newer python. 3.5 or 3.6, I guess.

Comment: @phd, yes, I am using python 3.6. I recently started coding in python, so I choose the last version. I didn't know about that, thanks. I suggest you to include the version of your code in the answer.